# How to parse an XML element which has keys and values separated by colons and newlines?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am currently working on a project where I have to get information out of a lot of XML Documents. Each document has an element header_text. There are a lot of values in there, which looks like that:

```
<header_text>
key1: val1
key2: val2
key3: val3
</header_text>
```

The keys are the same in each document, the values are sometimes empty.
I have a strong feeling that this is not standard XML, but I'm probably wrong?
Has anyone an idea how to parse these values quick and simple?

edit: I'm on python

Comment: For XML this is just a single text value (node). You need to use string functions to parse/read the key:value lines after reading the text using an XML api. How depends on the programming language/environment you're using.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'm using python. So I have to write something on my own to read those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use python and elementTree module to parse it:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial